# Process 'command 'npm'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: spring

I forked and cloned [spring.io/sagan](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan) project in my local labtop computer.

But I have some trouble building the project and I can't find an answer on how to solve the problem.

I am running Mac OS X Yosemite with the following software:

- gradle -v 2.3
- node -v 0.12.2
- npm -v 2.7.4
- What went wrong:

`Execution failed for task ':sagan-client:npmBuild'.
 Process 'command 'npm'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
 ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
 npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
 npm ERR! node v0.12.2
 npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! sagan@ build:`gulp build
 `npm ERR! Exit status 1
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! Failed at the sagan@ build script 'gulp build'.
 npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the sagan package,
 npm ERR! not with npm itself.
 npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
 npm ERR!     gulp build
 npm ERR! You can get their info via:
 npm ERR!     npm owner ls sagan
 npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
 npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
 npm ERR!     /Users/youngbinjang/git/sagan/sagan-client/npm-debug.log
 :sagan-client:npmBuild FAILED
 :sagan-client:npmBuild (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 1.907 secs.
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.`

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':sagan-client:npmBuild'.

> Process 'command 'npm'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   
>   Should I install Gulp? Any other tips?

Comment: were you using node v0.12? Build fails with this version as noted on this open github issue https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/issues/506

Answer (score 1):

My fix isn't necessarily related to Sagan, but it works:

I have linux system (pop OS/ "Ubuntu") with a recent version of node & npm.
But an outdated "default" version of node was used when I ran `gradle npm myTask`.
Just define a compatible version in `build.gradle` and it should be alright:

```
node {
    download = true
    version = "12.18.2"
}
```

(Doesn't have to be *this* node version!)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment on the question, Sagan build currently fails with node v0.12 ([see this open github issue](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/issues/506))

It builds fine with node v0.10. I was able to successfully build the project.

As a side note, the Node Version Manager [github link](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)) is quite handy for installing multiple versions of node and easily switching between different node versions depending on your needs. After installing NVM, I did the following:

```
nvm install 0.10
nvm alias default 0.10
open a new shell & build/run Sagan
```

(this will cause your machine to use node v0.10 by default. might want to switch back after you're done building/running Sagan).